# Как на Андроиде свернуть или закрыть браузер?

Tags: android, javascript

Доброго времени суток!

Как я могу закрыть окно браузера на Андроиде? Любыми способами, но предпочтительно `JavaScript`. Метод `window.close()` ... `window.blur()` в любых их реалиях не действуют.

**UPD1**:
Как открыть `WebView`, загрузить туда страницу а потом закрыть ее?

Answer (score 2):

В рамках JavaScript вряд ли...

А если с Java то если речь идет о том, чтобы закрыть `WebView` запущенный из вашей проги - то ответ [[@Gorets](/users/3608/gorets)](/users/3608/gorets) проканает. А если речь идет о том, чтобы закрыть браузер из другой программы - то это сложно:

1. Надо получить PID процесса - можно получить через `ActivityManager`
2. Зная PID процесса можно убить (kill) `android.os.Process.killProcess(process.pid);`

Это в теории, но на практике это обставлено тучей ограничений:

1. Надо иметь соотв. пермишен (что-типа `android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES`)
2. Процесс должен быть запущен тем-же юзером от имени которого пытаетесь убить или же надо обладать рут правами

Comment: Вот про WebView - то что надо! Можно подробнее? А то я пока дуб в этих технологиях :)

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: какие вопросы не четкие, а тут же только четкие пацаны ))) что значит открыть и тд? пальцем по экрану стукай пока не откроется браузер, потом вводи адресс, жди и закрывай)) а вообще уточни вопрос и

Answer (score 1):

activity.finish();

Comment: Это где так? Плюс я откопал, что браузер из другой программы не открыть. На мой вопрос, по ходу нет ответа.

Comment: когда запущена "другая программа", то браузер будет свернут. Учитывая специфику андроида, свернутый практически эквивалентно закрытый - просто так ведь закрыть программу на андроиде нельзя.

По моему мнению, закрывать окно броузера от нажатия кнопки - как то не очень, если только это не попап окно.